# MySQL explode string and remove last part

Tags: mysql, sql

I have string like

```
some1-some2-som3-123
some1-some2-143
some1-1235
```

How I can remove last part `-123` ? from that string with sql statment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simple `SUBSTRING` from beginning to last `-`:

```
SELECT col, SUBSTRING(col, 0, LENGTH(col) - INSTR(REVERSE(col), '-')) AS result
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41079/4/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║         col           ║      result      ║
╠═══════════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ some1-some2-som3-123  ║ some1-some2-som3 ║
║ some1-some2-143       ║ some1-some2      ║
║ some1-1235            ║ some1            ║
╚═══════════════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33652/3)

First find the last index of '-'

```
SELECT LENGTH("first-middle-last") - LOCATE('-', REVERSE("first-middle-last"));
```

Then extract the left part -

```
SELECT LEFT("first-middle-last", LENGTH("first-middle-last") - LOCATE('-', REVERSE("first-middle-last")));
```